# Missing bottom and right edge on text fields

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-text

I am using `tkinter` to build a very simple UI and I am using some text fields but they seem to miss the bottom and the right hand edging\bevel (unsure of the correct term).

There does appear to be ample space for the widget to render, I am posting here to see if this expected behaviour or a common\easily addressable issue.

I am using a grid layout and placing the widgets into the page like so:

```
runway_data_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
runway_data_text = tk.Text(load_frame, height=1, width=50, bg="light grey")
runway_data_text.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")
runway_data_text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

Here is a screen shot which shows what I am talking about. Some widgets have a grey background and some white, but the effect is apparent with both, regardless of the size I give the widget, I have underlined in blue where the effect is most obvious.

[image]

Here is a minimal reproducible example, where you can see there is a missing bottom and right edge to the text field:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False,False)
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("600x600")

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_control.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
style.configure("TFrame", background="white")
style.configure("TLabel", background="white", font=("URW Gothic L", "10", "bold"))
style.configure("TButton", font=("URW Gothic L", "10", "bold"))
style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", background="grey", font=("URW Gothic L","10"))
style.map("TNotebook.Tab", background=[("selected", "white")], font=[("selected", "bold")])

load_tab = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
load_frame = ttk.Frame(load_tab, padding=(8,8,12,12))
airport_data_label = ttk.Label(load_frame, text="Data", width=15, anchor="w")        
airport_data_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")        
airport_data_text = tk.Text(load_frame, height=1, width=50, bg="light grey")
airport_data_text.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
airport_data_text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
airport_data_btn = tk.Button(load_frame, text="Open", command=lambda: print("Hello")).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")
load_frame.pack()

tab_control.add(load_tab, text="Load Data")

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a screen shot from the MRE:

[image]

Comment: If I remember right. The width of the `Text` widget is specified in character not in pixel. That should causes the widget to be bigger than the window. therefore there is no edge, while there is no end. Other useful parameters in this case are `borderwidth` / `bd` and `highlightthickness`.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand your problem better?

Comment: @SriramSrinivasan I have created a MRE, apologies for the delay, its a public holiday here today.

Comment: I am not sure of how to display the bottom and right edges, but if you are mainly interested in *uniformity*, you can remove all the edges using `bd=0` in `tk.Text(load_frame, ...)`.

Comment: I would like to understand why I am missing these edges and rectify the problem rather than removing them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After observing all the `reliefs` carefully, I realised that some of them (`raised`, `sunken`, `ridge`, `groove`) give a 3D appearance to the border by adding shadows to some edges. This gives the illusion that some edges are missing.

On the other hand, `solid` adds a uniform 2D border and `flat` adds a flat border that has the same colour as the background colour of the widget.

[image]

---

### Solution:

If you want all the edges to be visible, you can use the `solid` relief. Also, you can change the border thickness by changing the value of `bd`.

```py
airport_data_text = tk.Text(load_frame, height=1, width=50, bg="light grey", relief = "solid", bd = 1)
```

[image]